# Why a {get;private set} List's content can be changed?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
class Foo {
  List<Object> myList {get;private set;}
}
```

then in other script, I can still do this

```
foo.myList.Add(new Object());
```

I know it is just allowed but why? what is the design logic behind this? If you can add/remove stuff from the list then it is really not a *private* set.

Comment: It is a private set but it isn't a private get so you can access the list's Add method, which is public.

Comment: It's sufficient that you have a public getter, you can then do *anything* you like with the object returned from the getter. However you cannot *set* the `mylist` (e.g. `foo.mylist = new List<Object>()` ).

Comment: A list is like a bag and because of the private set you cannot change the bag, but you can use the bag (fill, empty, ...)

Comment: you could have a private `List<T>` and the property could return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as suggested in MSDN's **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)**  In so doing, consumers cannot change the collection or the contents

Comment: You're not changing the value of `myList`. You're just calling a method on it, which only invokes `get`

Comment: If there's confusion over a read-only property, there's also room for the same confusion with a `ReadOnlyCollection`. It keeps consumers from modifying the collection, but it doesn't keep consumers from modifying the individual items in the collection if they are mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you return an object from a property or method, the recipient has a reference to that object and can call its properties or methods. If that object has settable properties or methods that change its state, the recipient can modify the object. (Or they could pass the object to something else that modifies it.)

Making `set` `private` just means that another class can't set the property to a different list or to null. But when another class gets a reference to that list, it can call the `Add`, `Clear`, or any other method.

If you want to protect the contents of your list you could do this:

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Object> _myList;
    IReadOnlyList<Object> MyList => _myList.AsReadOnly();
    // or IReadOnlyCollection. 
    // Items in a IReadOnlyList are accessible by index.
}
```

Internally the class has a list, but other classes can only access a readonly collection of items in the list. They can't modify the collection.

However, by returning a list of objects, the recipient does have access to each of those objects. They don't somehow become "read only." If they have settable properties or methods that change their internal state, they can still be modified.

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>` object cannot be changed, but its contents can. Like if you go to a shop and its catalog is clamped to the desk - you can still add/remove pages from it.

If you wanted similar semantics (to guard against a consumer of your class from modifying the `List<T>` you could return an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, like this

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Object> _myList;

    public IEnumerable<Object> MyEnumerable
    {
        get
        {
            return _myList;
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to use `MyEnumerable` you can, for instance, create a collection from it (e.g. call [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
List<object> list = foo.MyEnumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: I don't recommend returning `IEnumerable<T>` because it doesn't allow for random-access by index. I recommend returning it as `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead, though consumers can cast this back to a normal `IList<T>`. I recommend using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead as it's the safest.

Comment: The only *real* way of guarding against somebody modifying whatever you're returning would be to create a new collection (or create an iterator by making the property `yield return` the values). I agree with you about the `ReadOnlyCollection` though. I'll not modify my answer to include your recommendation as other answers already cover this.

Answer (score 0):

if a `reference` type allows read access, its `public` methods are exposed as well. in this case, `.Add()`. it's important to remember that the state of `myList` is mutable but the `reference` to it cannot be changed externally.

Answer (score 0):

`private set` means you (outside the class) cannot set myList to a different list. It doesn't mean that the list contents the myList points at cannot be changed

Ie you it means you cannot do this

```
myFoo.myList = new List<Object>();
```

but (as you found out) you can do this

```
myFoo.myList.Add(o);
```